# I'm getting no output from this while loop I wrote

Tags: matlab, math, while-loop

I've been trying to create a code that can do the bisection method to find roots of equations on MATLAB and so far I was not able to get it to run. Originally the if statement was outside of the while loop, but then I switched it out to see if it does anything. Instead, I've been getting no output from it in the command window. Any help and explanations for how this happens is much appreciated.

```
function [x_root] = bisection(func,x_low,x_high,accuracy)


x_root = (x_low+x_high)/2;
f_low=func(x_low);
f_high=func(x_high);
f_root=func(x_root);

if (f_low*f_high)<=0
    x_root=(x_low+x_high)/2;
    iterations = 0;
    while abs(x_root) > accuracy
        iterations = iterations + 1;
        x_root = (x_low+x_high)/2;
        if (f_low*f_root) < 0
            x_high=x_root;
        else
            x_low=x_root;
        end
        

    end
    
else
    error('There is no root')
end
```

Comment: How are you calling this function? (What do you enter in the MATLAB command window?)

Comment: And what about the other inputs?

Comment: I think your code looks a bit over-complicated. Take a look at the answer provided at this [link](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/483519-bisection-method-code-mathlab#answer_394744). I just recommend adding a few spaces to make it easier to read: `f(c)<0&&f(a)<0` should be `f(c)<0 && f(a)<0`.

Comment: I assign my function to a variable, let's use a = @(x)sin(2*x) and then I use 'a' as an input for the function so it will look like bisection(a, -2,2,.001). When I try to put the function directly in as an input, I get an error that says "Invalid expression. Check for missing multiplication
operator, missing or unbalanced delimiters, or other syntax error.
To construct matrices, use brackets instead of parentheses.

Comment: If you use the much simpler function that I gave the link to, then it gives the correct result. I suggest you try to read and understand that function because it is extremely short and I think it's very clear how it works.

Comment: Solved it! Thanks